# post httpwebrequest in c# uses large amount of memory

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, google-cloud-messaging

I am using the following gcm class to post data to send a gcm notification to about 10,000 android devices:

```
class GCMandroid
{
    private JArray RegIDs;
    private string tickerText;
    private string level;
    private string id;
    private string title;
    private string message;
    private string date;

    public GCMandroid(List<string> Ids,string tickerText,string level,string id,
        string title,string message,string date)
    {
        this.RegIDs = new JArray(Ids.ToArray());
        this.tickerText = tickerText;
        this.level = level;
        this.id = id;
        this.date = date;
        this.title = title;
        this.message = message;
    }
    public string GetPostData()
    {
        string postData =
            "{ \"registration_ids\": " + this.RegIDs + ", " +
            "\"time_to_live\":" + "43200" + ", " +
            "\"collapse_key\":\"" + "Key" + "\", " +
            "\"data\": {\"tickerText\":\"" + this.tickerText + "\", " +
            "\"level\":\"" + this.level + "\", " +
            "\"id\":\"" + this.id + "\", " +
            "\"date\":\"" + this.date + "\", " +
            "\"title\":\"" + this.title + "\", " +
            "\"message\": \"" + this.message + "\"}}";
        return postData;
    }
    public bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public string SendGCMNotification(string apiKey, string postData, string postDataContentType = "application/json")
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);

        //
        // MESSAGE CONTENT
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

        //
        // CREATE REQUEST
        HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
        Request.Method = "POST";
        Request.KeepAlive = false;
        Request.ContentType = postDataContentType;
        Request.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", apiKey));
        Request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

        Stream dataStream = Request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();

        //
        // SEND MESSAGE
        try
        {
            WebResponse Response = Request.GetResponse();
            HttpStatusCode ResponseCode = ((HttpWebResponse)Response).StatusCode;
            if (ResponseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) || ResponseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden))
            {
                var text = "Unauthorized - need new token";
            }
            else if (!ResponseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.OK))
            {
                var text = "Response from web service isn't OK";
            }

            StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream());
            string responseLine = Reader.ReadToEnd();
            Reader.Close();
            Response.Close();
            return responseLine;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        return "error";
    }
}
```

this is used in a windows form that contain a timer and each 10 seconds will tick a background worker if it is not busy to fetch data from database and send it to about 10,000 android devices with calling :

```
GCMandroid gcm = new GCMandroid(sublist, tickerText, level, id, title, message,date);
gcm.SendGCMNotification(AndroidApiKey, gcm.GetPostData());
```

where `sublist` is max 1000 as the gcm cloud quota per each request. the notification is recieved well but the programs uses large amount of memory.

after removing functions while trying to detect the main part of the project that is causing the ram usage (2 GB of memory used by the process in 4 days) I found that sending the notification is causing this ram usage.

I searched for problems of ram usage with httpwebrequset and didn't find anything related. I also tried to call the garbage collector but it doesn't clear all the memory a big part stays used; it clears only about 5% of the total RAM memory used. Can anybody help to stop this large memory usage.

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with SendGCMNotification(), my guess is that the leak (if there is one) is caused by something else in the app. You need to explain how you reached the conclusion that "I found that sending the notification is causing this ram usage."
Also, why are you calling ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback each time?

Comment: Be sure to dispose of everything that is disposable. For instance, your Stream, StreamReader, and WebResponse. Safest bet is to do: `using (Stream dataStream = Request.GetRequestStream()) { ... }`

Comment: @gooid I launch the application without sending the notification for 3-4 days the memory used remains about 20-25 MB when I launch it with sending notification the problem occurs.

Comment: @MikeRichards can you clarify more in an answer

Answer (score 0):

Your GetPostData function is appending massive amounts of strings. Use a StringBuilder instead.

Comment: His function is not "appending" to a string, it is concatenating. Since it is a fixed number of concatetation operations, String is suggested instead of StringBuilder. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: the new GetPostData is:
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("{ \"registration_ids\": ").Append(this.RegIDs);
sb.Append(", \"time_to_live\":43200, \"collapse_key\":\"News\", \"data\": {\"tickerText\":\"").Append(this.tickerText);
sb.Append("\", \"level\":\"").Append(this.level).Append("\", ");
sb.Append("\"id\":\"").Append(this.id).Append("\", ");
.....

sb.Append("\"message\":\"").Append(this.message).Append("\"}}");
string postData = sb.ToString();
return postData;
I'll try

Comment: same result; in 3 hours it uses 168 MB